# Pass a row record to Oracle procedure using System.Data.OracleClient

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracleclient

I would like to pass 51 plus parameter to an oracle stored procedure, i would like to pass them as a collection/array or custom object. I know its possible using assiative arrays using ODP driver but I am using OracleClient. How will I be able to achieve this, would not like to pass 50 plus fields as individual parameters.

Comment: AFAIK, The .NET OracleClient does not support that. Probably one of the reasons it has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a record as a string with values separated by a pipe (|) or any character of your choice.
On database end split the passed string values.

Not the optimal solution but it works.

Comment: Please do not do this... You or your company spent all of that money on Oracle database for a reason. Try generating the code using Oracle metadata tables... i.e. USER_ARGUMENTS, USER_TABLES, etc.